# C# rename namespaces during build

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am looking for a way to rename namespaces in an 3-rd party assembly during build process (and corresponding using statements in user code). I searched through fody's weavers but haven't found such thing. There is a pull request to ILRepack that does exact thing but it seems to be stale and not passing CI: https://github.com/gluck/il-repack/pull/268

Lets say I have two projects, A and B, both are nugetized and B has package dependency on A. Since I do not want to lock consumer on specific version on A when referencing B I am merging A into B with ILRepack and internalize A there, but despite A being internalized in B there is a type ambiguity on classes from A when consumer uses A and B in his project C.

NEST package (elasticsearch client https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net) has done the exact thing with Newtonsoft.Json package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. There are two solutions:

#### ILRepack

ILRepack has options `Internalize` and `RenameInternalized`. `Internalize` will change public modifiers to internal for merged assemblies while `RenameInternalized` will append some random guids to these type names. All usages are also correctly renamed.

#### Assembly Rewriter

https://github.com/nullean/assembly-rewriter

Dotnet tool that rewrites assemblies and rename namespaces. It is limited to root namespace that is the same as assembly file name.